# maximal subgroups of $GL_2(Z/p^kZ)$

Tags: linear-algebra, gr.group-theory

Hello, 
is there any classification of proper maximal subroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})$ for $k>1$ (analogous to the one which exist for $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$)? 
Could you give me some references? 
thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the classification you mention related to the case $k=1$?

Comment: You can ask for all $k$ at once by asking for the maximal open subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. There are only finitely many of them as this group is finitely generated and virtually pro-$p$.

Comment: @leandro : for $k=1$ for instance Serre J. P. Propriétés galoisiennes des points d'ordre fini des courbes elliptiques. 

Comment: @colin : yes but I am interested in a description at the level $p^k$ for a fixed $k$ (in the same flavour that the description for $k=1$). Maybe it is easy, please tell me. I am in trouble by some "bizarreries", for instance of course a proper maximal subgroup at the level $p^k$ can be not yet proper for $p^j, j<k$. 

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe this paper is useful. For example, it contains a big list of references: http://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/o.h.king/KingBCC05.pdf

Comment: @Marusia: If I remember correctly, this particular type of "bizarre" behaviour does not occur for $p>3$: In the paper that you mention, Serre has a group-theoretic argument to prove that when a subgroup of $GL_2(Z_p)$ surjects onto $SL_2(F_p)$, it must contain the whole of $SL_2(Z_p)$. So it easy to classify maximal subgroups that are "not proper at level $p$", just by looking at the determinant. For $p=2$ and 3 there are indeed proper maximal subgroups that surject onto $GL_2(F_p)$ - e.g. this is in http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5031 for $p=2$ and Elkies' paper referenced in there for $p=3$.

Comment: sorry : I never tanked for your answers so I just do it : thank you very much! 